# Redirect via htcaccess

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, redirect

I need your help.

I have a site which I have just moved to a new domain. I want all pages on the old domain, except from one, redirected to the root of the new domain.

The one page I don't want redirected to the new domain root should be redirected to a specific page on the new domain.

Is that possible to do at the same time and how?

**OLD domain** (HTML)
www.karensunivers.com (all pages except one, should be redirected to below)
**NEW domain** (PHP)
www.karensuniverse.com

**SPECIAL page redirect:**
**OLD page link** (HTML)
www.karensunivers.com/anette-lovdal-meditation.html
**NEW page link** (PHP)
www.karensuniverse.com/meditation/anette-lovdal

Hope someone are able to help me out!

Thanks in advance and Merry Christmas!

BR
Ronni

Comment: http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/redirects/setting-up-a-301-permanent-redirect-via-htaccess

Answer (score 0):

if you want to redirect a entire site as is, add :

```
Redirect 301 / http://newsite.com/
```

To your htaccess, but if page urls have completely changed ( if you've done a total rebuild of a site) you'll have to add one for each page, like:

```
 Redirect 301 /oldpage.html http://www.yoursite.com/newpage.html
 Redirect 301 /oldpage2.html http://www.yoursite.com/folder/
```

This way you will not ruin your google seo ratings for pages

In your situation i'd use my first snippet to redirect all to the new domain and on your new domain add this to your new htaccess:

```
 Redirect 301 /anette-lovdal-meditation.html /meditation/anette-lovdal
```

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
Perfect - Thanks a lot Jason!

Have a Happy New Year!

Ronni